# entrypointnotfoundexception for sfcIsFileProtected

Tags: c#, pinvoke

My code was working like a charm till i install windows u update on my 64-bit laptop and I started getting `EntryPointNotFoundException` while using sfcFileProtected.

I tried using

```
[DllImport("sfc.dll", EntryPoint = "sfc_os.SfcIsFileProtected")]
```

and even

```
[DllImport("sfc.dll", EntryPoint = "SfcIsFileProtected")]
```

but not working.

I am counting on the community. Please help.

Comment: Change the DLL name from sfc.dll to sfc_os.dll

Comment: @Hans:Awesome it worked. I don't understand why it worked in first place? Do i need to add a OS and architecture check before i call these API?